# Python, where to add a 2nd loop

Tags: python, for-loop

This is my function

```
    def offer(rent_start, rent_end, website):
        driver.get(website[0])
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="btnUpdateQuote"]').click()
```

This is my 1st for loop

```
phones = ["https://xxxxxx/", "phones"]
laptops = ["https://xxxxxx/", "laptops"]
headsets = ["https://xxxxxx/", "headsets"]
keyboards = ["https://xxxxxx/", "keyboards"]

websites_list = [phones,laptops,headsets,keyboards]

for website in websites_list:
    offer(rent_start, rent_end, website)
```

I would like to add the following 2nd for loop in my code, so that first the date is selected and then the website opened. So for example 17 June 2021 selected and then [phones,laptops,headsets,keyboards] are requested. After that 19 June 2021 (+ 2 days) is selected and [phones,laptops,headsets,keyboards] are requested

```
rent_start = date(2022, 6, 19)
add_to_rent_start = int(2)
alternate_days = timedelta(days=add_to_rent_start)
rent_end = rent_start + alternate days

alternate_days_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]
for alt_days in alternate_days_list:
    alternate_days = timedelta(days=add_to_rent_start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
alternate_days_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]

for alt_days in alternate_days_list:
    rent_start = date(2022, 6, 19)
    alternate_days = timedelta(days=alt_days)
    rent_end = rent_start + alternate days

    for website in websites_list:
        offer(rent_start, rent_end, website)
```

Then, you can request each URL with alternate_days_list.

Comment: Thx for the quikc reply, will try this.

Comment: Thx @Lazyer, much appreciation